# Plot the run time of three functions

Tags: r, plot

I have three functions doing the same task but in a different way:

Function 1:

```
f1 <- function(n) {
  sum = 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    sum <- sum + a(i)
  }
  return(sum)
}
```

Function 2:

```
f4 <- function(n) {
  sum = 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    sum <- sum + b(i)
  }
  return(sum)
}
```

Function 3:

```
f3 <- function(n) {
  #Done using lgamma
  sum = 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    sum = sum + c(i)
  }
  return(sum)
}
```

I need to plot the runtime of these 3 functions over a range of values 1 - n using `user` time from `system.time`. How can this be done in R?

Comment: where are the functions log_gamma_loop and log_gamma_recursive?

Comment: Seems tou allready know to use `system.time`. You just have to save it to a numeric variable and plot that variable.

Comment: @Florian Added the helper functions

Comment: @DrorBogin Could you show with an example

Comment: This will be an easy example.                                    `A = system.time(print("hello world"));
B = A[1];
as.numeric(B)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `microbenchmark` to time your functions, and `ggplot2` to plot. Here is an example:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

max_n = 15
results = data.frame(sum_lgamma=numeric(max_n),
                     sum_log_gamma_recursive = numeric(max_n),
                     sum_log_gamma_loop = numeric(max_n),
                     id = seq(max_n))
for(i in 1:max_n)
{
  results$sum_lgamma[i] = median(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum_lgamma(i))$time)
  results$sum_log_gamma_loop[i] = median(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum_log_gamma_loop(i))$time)
  results$sum_log_gamma_recursive[i] = median(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum_log_gamma_recursive(i))$time)
}
results = melt(results, id.vars=c("id"))

ggplot(results, aes(x=id,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: What is meant by `numeric(max_n)` ? Why can't it just be `max_n`?

Comment: It creates an empty numeric of length `max_n`. Probably just doing `= 0` does exactly the same.